# Argument from vastness of universe to moral insignificance

Tags: ethics

One might argue from the vastness of the universe, or rather
from the vastness of inevitable suffering in it, that the moral
significance of acting such as to minimize suffering is close to
zero, since the difference between total suffering and
total suffering minus what one prevented is close to zero.  Does
this or a similar argument play any role in philosophical
literature?

(I have rewritten this, since I seemed to be taken before to be concerned with the size of the universe in itself.)

Comment: No, one might not. There is no relation between physical size and moral significance, one has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: @Conifold, the argument may be bad; that doesn't mean it mightn't be made.

Comment: True, but philosophical literature usually stays away from arguments that are transparently invalid. You will find arguments along the lines of "natural laws are indifferent to morality, so naturalism can not account for moral value", but they do the opposite of tying moral value to natural phenomena. Pascal expressed it more poetically:"*When I consider the short duration of my life, swallowed up in an eternity before and after, the little space I fill engulfed in the infinite immensity of spaces whereof I know nothing, and which know nothing of me, I am terrified.*" Emotion, not argument.

Comment: i don't see how the size of the universe makes any difference to ethics. Feynman made a similar point but the argument is not a good one.

Comment: My personal opinion - this kind of thought was created by scientism (and logical positivism).

Comment: If relative physical size and moral significance are correlated, it would suggest that big people are morally more significant than little people. So a little person who kills is less immoral than a very big person? Seems to stretch credibility a tad.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss IMO science doesn't really promote ignoring the effects of things just because they occur on a scale that is small compared to something else.  Especially in cases like this where the scale definitely has an effect on the system in question (i.e. morality effects your own life and the lives around you, even if it doesn't necessarily effect the entire universe noticeably).

Answer (score 5):

Thomas Nagel, in his famous article ["The Absurd"](https://philosophy.as.uky.edu/sites/default/files/The%20Absurd%20-%20Thomas%20Nagel.pdf), mentions a similar argument about the meaning of life:

> What we say to convey the absurdity of our lives often has to
>   do with space or time: we are tiny specks in the infinite vastness of
>   the universe; our lives are mere instants even on a geological time
>   scale, let alone a cosmic one; we will all be dead any minute.

He then responds:

> But of course none of these evident facts can be what makes life absurd,
>   if it is absurd. For suppose we lived forever; would not a life that is
>   absurd if it lasts seventy years be infinitely absurd if it lasted
>   through eternity? And if our lives are absurd given our present
>   size, why would they be any less absurd if we filled the universe
>   (either because we were larger or because the universe was smaller)?

A similar point could be made in response to your argument. What difference would it make if the size of the universe were smaller? If a given action is morally insignificant, it's not at all clear why it would be any more significant if the universe were much smaller.

Perhaps that thought is that the moral significance of an action depends on (or is identical to) its effect on the entire universe. But that seems to confuse *moral* significance with some other notion of significance. At least, the major moral theories are not committed to such a claim, and neither are the main arguments for [moral skepticism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/skepticism-moral/).

Comment: We can think about the 'vastness of the universe', but is it the case that the universe thinks about us as 'specks', or even thinks at all? Perhaps it's not the size of the dog in the fight, but the fight in the dog! Why are we always inclined to demean ourselves and our innate talents?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a bit like that old teenage argument that things are just going to get dirty again, so what's the point in cleaning the house...

That fact that there is a vast amount of dirt in the world does not mean that we should stop trying to keep our little corner of the world clean. Keeping our little corner clean is good for us, physically and psychologically. The more that people do it, the more we create an environment that we are all happy to live in. The same is true for moral acts.  Easing the suffering of one person might not shake the universe to its core, but it means a lot to that one person, and it makes our little corner of the universe a better, nicer place.

If we were a universal mind drifting through the cosmos, we could look down at far distant Earth and contemplate the moral insignificance of the ant-like creatures that crawl along its surface. But we're not. We are embodied, present, and engaged with our little world, such that every moral consideration is up-close and personal. Casting ourselves in the role of a drifting universal mind is a denial of who and what we are.

Comment: Please make it clearer how this answers the question.

Comment: @Toothrot: I'm not certain how much clearer I can be, without micro-explaining what the analogy. Perhaps if you told me what dissatisfies you about this answer..?

Comment: I asked whether this argument plays any role in philosophical literature, not whether it is a good argument, nor how one might respond to it.

Comment: @Ah, sorry. The only place you're going to find that argument is from someone writing in the nihilist worldview, but nihilism doesn't have much standing in academic philosophy — nihilism usually appears there as a *devil's advocate* type of argument — and from what little I know of that worldview, I can't think of anyone who has made that particular argument. It's easy enough to undercut moral philosophy for more conventional reasons (e.g., biological determinism or anti-deontological claims), so there's really no need to bring matters of scale into the picture.